# will encrypted value change in c#?

Tags: c#, encryption

in C#, if i use some encrypt such as Rfc2898DeriveBytes() to encrypt a string, will the encrypted value always be the same? I know it will produce some random value, but will the random value change?

for example, the following code:

```
public static void Main(string[] passwordargs)
    {
    try
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes k1 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(pwd1, salt1,myIterations);
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes k2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(pwd1, salt1);
            // Encrypt the data.
            Aes encAlg = Aes.Create();
            encAlg.Key = k1.GetBytes(16);
            MemoryStream encryptionStream = new MemoryStream();
            CryptoStream encrypt = new CryptoStream(encryptionStream,encAlg.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            byte[] utfD1 = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(false).GetBytes(data1);

            encrypt.Write(utfD1, 0, utfD1.Length);
            encrypt.FlushFinalBlock();
            encrypt.Close();
            byte[] edata1 = encryptionStream.ToArray();
            k1.Reset();

            // Try to decrypt, thus showing it can be round-tripped.
            Aes decAlg = Aes.Create();
            decAlg.Key = k2.GetBytes(16);
            decAlg.IV = encAlg.IV;
            MemoryStream decryptionStreamBacking = new MemoryStream();
            CryptoStream decrypt = new CryptoStream(decryptionStreamBacking, decAlg.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            decrypt.Write(edata1, 0, edata1.Length);
            decrypt.Flush();
            decrypt.Close();
            k2.Reset();
            string data2 = new UTF8Encoding(false).GetString(decryptionStreamBacking.ToArray());
 }
```

Comment: Please explain a bit more. How did you encrypt it? And a random value is random by definition. If you mean will that class return the same result every time with the same parameters, then yes.

Comment: Encryption never produces "some random value". It can't - otherwise you wouldn't be able to decrypt.

Comment: i saw pseudo random on msdn, also in some of the answers below. To make my question more clear, for example, if I have a password abcdefg, and if I use Rfc2898DeriveBytes() to encrypt it, will the output value always be the same no matter how many times you run it? I guess some answers already solved this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rfc2898DeriveBytes is a Password Based Key Derivation Function (PBKDF). It implements PBKDF2, which is a specific PBKDF algorithm.

It is *not* a cipher by itself; it cannot be used directly to encrypt anything. PKCS#5, which defines "Password Based Decryption" and *includes* PBKDF2 as well as methods for encryption/decryption.

---

PBKDF2 takes a few parameters:

- an iteration count
- a salt value, which should be different for each password
- the password itself as bytes
- the required size of the output, say `s`

it outputs the derived "key" or "password hash" value, consisting of `s` bytes.

The iteration count is usually a configuration parameter. If you use the string based methods then .NET will convert the password using UTF-8 (but you could convert to bytes yourself). Possibly the work is repeated if more bytes are required than generated by the underlying cryptographic hash function (SHA-1 or SHA-2).

The salt value is generally generated anew for each new password and each password change. It should consist of 8 to 16 bytes or so.

The output is not dependent on how many bytes are requested or how. Asking for 2 bytes or requesting 1 bytes first and 1 byte later should not differ.

---

PBKDF2 in itself is a **pseudo random** function, which means that if you don't change any of the input parameters that you will get the same output.

If you assume that the iteration count, and the encoded password do not change, then the PBKDF2 output will only be random (in time) if the salt changes (in time).

---

The output of PBKDF2 can be used for 2 different purposes:

- as password hash to compare the stored value with a password hash to be verified, protecting the password itself
- to generate a secret / symmetric key for a cipher

---

Note that the cipher mode should use an IV. An IV itself can also be random or pseudo random (e.g. generated itself by PBKDF2). This means that the ciphertext may still be random even if the key itself is only pseudo-random; it depends on how the IV is generated.

Comment: Thanks @Maarten for a great explanation.

Answer (score -2):

Rfc2898DeriveBytes takes a password, a salt, and an iteration count, and then generates keys through calls to the GetBytes method. It's a pseudo-random function so the value will not be the same.

Comment: Of course it's going to be the same if you use the same inputs.

Comment: For the same input yes but he didn't say he want to encrypt the same input...

Comment: How do you know? The question is not perfectly clear. It could mean anything.

Comment: It would be a bit of a dopey question if the OP means will a different input always produce the same output. I think we must conclude that the OP is using the same input string.

Comment: It also is not encryption. Encryption indicates a way to decrypt. This is a HASH.